# How to call function inside ui-route state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am new to angular,i need know how to call function next to the `roles` instead of `[]` need to call function , in the below example:-

```
state('signin', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/signin',
        data: {
            roles: [] //Here i need to call function Becuase i need 
                        assign values like this roles: ['dev','Admin'] 
                        (need to know how to call function here)
        },
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: '/signin.html' },
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: '/index.html',
                controller: 'SigninCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

If , i am trying with resoleve like below example:-

```
   .state('signin', {
    parent: 'site',
    url: '/signin',

    views: {
        '': { templateUrl: '/signin.html' },
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: '/index.html',
            controller: 'SigninCtrl'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        TrackerApp: function ($q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            roles: Loadrole()
            defer.resolve();
            return defer.promise();
        }

    }
})
```

Getting Error like:-

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

if am putting roles inside resolve getting above error

Comment: You may use `resolve` instead of `data`.

Comment: Uluk Biy , i have tried using resolve getting error i have updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Your resolve method must be like this:

```
resolve: {
            "trackerApp" : "TrackerApp",
            "roles" : trackerApp.getRoles();
     }
```

Move the data fetching part to service method like `getRoles()`. Assign it to `roles` property which will be available in your controller scope.